# Strange behavior of dmvnorm

Tags: r

It appears dnorm(x) and dmvnorm(x) (from mvtnorm package v1.0.5) generates the same result when x is of length 1. However, when working with integration function, the result for dmvnorm(x) seems to be quite off. Here is the example, I defined two integrand functions:

```
integrand1 <- function(x) 
{ pnorm((-2-sqrt(0.2)*x)/sqrt(0.8))*dmvnorm(x)} 

integrand2 <- function(x) 
{ pnorm((-2-sqrt(0.2)*x)/sqrt(0.8))*dnorm(x)}
```

When evaluating at individual values, integrand1(x) = integrand2(x).

However, integration along these two functions generates totally different results:

```
integrate(integrand1,lower = -10,upper = 10)$value
[1] 7.567463e-236

integrate(integrand2,lower = -10,upper = 10)$value
[1] 0.02275013
```

Similar phenomena is also observed for *curve* function. Just wonder if it is a bug or I use it incorrectly.

Comment: use `dmvnorm(matrix(x))`

Comment: Did you try `dnorm(1:10)` and `dmvnorm(1:10)`? Do you understand why they differ? Why `dmvnorm(1:10)` is basically equal to `prod(dnorm(1:10))`?

Comment: Thanks, @user20650. dmvnorm(matrix(x)) solves the problem.

Comment: @nicola, thanks for your comments. Actually I don't know the difference between dnorm(1:10) and dmvnorm(1:10). Could you kindly elaborate it a bit more on the difference? Thanks.

Comment: I made an answer. See if it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bug. The `dmvnorm` function expects to evaluate the density distribution function of a multinormal, while `dnorm` handle single variate distributions. Let's see an example:

```
dnorm(1:5)
#[1] 2.419707e-01 5.399097e-02 4.431848e-03 1.338302e-04 1.486720e-06    
dmvnorm(1:5)
#[1] 1.151999e-14
```

First difference: `dnorm` returns a vector of length 5, while `dmvnorm` a single value. We note also that:

```
prod(dnorm(1:5))
#[1] 1.151999e-14
```

basically the same value returned by `dmvnorm`. In short, these are the difference:

- `dnorm(1:5)` evaluates the density of a normal distribution at 1, then 2, 3, 4 and 5 with mean 0 and standard deviation 1. So we have 5 values.
- `dmvnorm` is made to treat *multivariate* distributions. We now ask which are the density of a 5-variate multinormal (since we provided `1:5`, i.e. a vector of length 5) where the first variable is at 1, the second at 2 and so on. The means are all zeroes and the covariance matrix is `diag(5)`, i.e. a 5 dimensional identity matrix. Both are the default values, since we didn't specify them. See `?dmvnorm`.

In the latter case, the five variable are *independent* and so the density is the product of 5 independent (single-variate) normal distribution at 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

Use `dnorm` when you are dealing with single-variate distributions and `dmvnorm` otherwise.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @nicola. This is very helpful!

Comment: Thanks, @nicola. I also noticed that in terms of run-time, prod(dnorm(x)) appears to be much faster than dmvnorm(x) when length(x)>1. Can you share some lights on the performance difference?

Comment: Hi @Lamothy. It may happen because `dmvnorm` solves a system and it is written in R. `dnorm` is written in C and only needs to evaluate the function in one point (even tough you have to multiply all of them latter)